# obtener el numero de filas de una base sql server para mostrar en php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

quiero msotrar el numero de filas de una tabla en SQL server
mi sentencia es :

```
$result12 = sqlsrv_num_rows($conn, "SELECT asistencia FROM asistencia");
```

pero no me esta entregando ningun resultado al tratar de mostrarlo en php teniendo en mi base de datos 100 resultados

```
<?php echo $result12; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentalo asi:

```
$result2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT asistencia FROM asistencia");

$result = sqlsrv_num_rows( $result2 );

echo $result;
```

Comment: hola, muchas gracisas , me parese extraño ya que no me esta entregando ningun resultado en mi proyecto , es necesario mostrarlo con algun formato o algo?

Comment: No, talvez no tienes registros en tu tabla, tienes algo mal en tu query, o estas mostrando mal el resultado.

Comment: ya loprobe en otro lado yes correcto creo que es algo de los valores de la tabla , pero ya me funciono muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

al final encontre el problema
 
refiriendome al usuario alalp:

> It is because sqlsrv_query() uses SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD cursor type by
>   default. However, in order to get a result from sqlsrv_num_rows(), you
>   should choose one of these cursor types below:
>
> SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET
>   SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED For more information, check: Cursor
>   Types (SQLSRV Driver)
>
> In conclusion, if you use your query like:
>
> $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $result, array(), array( "Scrollable" =>
>   'static' )); you will get result in:
>
> $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);

elproblema es que en SQL serverno elcount(*) o sqlsrv_num_rows yaque es unmetododistintocomo recuperala informacion, asi nada mas no entreganingun resultado

el metodocorrecto es (en sqlsrv )

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM asistencia";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );

$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );

if ($row_count === false)
   echo "Error in retrieveing row count.";
else
   echo $row_count;
?>
```

si me costo mucho trabajo encontrar por que no entrega resultados de la manera que me compartio (y muchasd gracias otraves) el compañero alanfcm

espero que le sea util a alguien .